# how to implement pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm developing my master thesis in time series analysis and I´m creating a framework, where I use pandas.

To save my data I want to use pandas.Dataframe. However, I want to design the system in an abstract way, in order for future changes.

My "dataframe class" is the following:

```
class TimeSeries(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = none

    def read_csv(self, filename):
        self._data = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

My problem is: 
I can´t access rows and columns the same way as I do if I create a pandas.dataframe. 
For example:

```
df = pandas.read_csv("my_file.csv")
print(df['Date'])
```

Doesn't has the same behavior if I have:

```
time_series = TimeSeries() #the class I defined above
time_series.read_csv("my_file.csv")
print(time_series['Date']) #ERRO
```

Can you help me find out what I'm doing wrong and what I need to do to achieve my goal?

Thank you!!

Comment: you should use `time_series._data['Date']`

Comment: Thank you!! It worked

Comment: Do you know any way to not use the '._data'?

Comment: chnage your read_csv method to return the object `return TimeSeries(pd.read_csv(filename))`